# How do I make Storybook run both React AND Svelte

Tags: reactjs, svelte, storybook

I want to write stories for both React and Svelte components. I already have a few React components, and I'm attempting to install Svelte. My closest attempt can either run React OR Svelte depending on whether I comment out my React configuration. If I don't comment it out, I get this message when I look at my Svelte component in storybook:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Component}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in unboundStoryFn
    in ErrorBoundary
    (further stack trace)
```

This refers to my story `stories/test.svelte-stories.js`:

```js
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/svelte';
import TestSvelteComponent from '../src/testComponentGroup/TestSvelteComponent.svelte';

storiesOf('TestSvelteComponent', module)
  .add('Svelte Test', () => ({
    Component: TestSvelteComponent
  }));
```

My configuration is as follows:

`.storybook/config.js`:

```js
import './config.react'; // If I comment out this line, I can make the svelte component work in storybook, but of course my react stories won't appear.
import './config.svelte';
```

`.storybook/config.react.js`:

```js
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';

const req = require.context('../stories', true, /\.react-stories\.js$/);
function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

`.storybook/config.svelte.js`:

```js
import { configure } from '@storybook/svelte';

const req = require.context('../stories', true, /\.svelte-stories\.js$/);
function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

`.storybook/webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  let j;
  // Find svelteloader from the webpack config
  const svelteloader = config.module.rules.find((r, i) => {
      if (r.loader && r.loader.includes('svelte-loader')) {
          j = i;
          return true;
      }
  });

  // safely inject preprocess into the config
  config.module.rules[j] = {
      ...svelteloader,
      options: {
          ...svelteloader.options,
      }
  }

  // return the overridden config
  return config;
}
```

`src/testComponentGroup/TestSvelteComponent.svelte`:

```html
<h1>
    Hello
</h1>
```

It seems as though it's attempting to parse JSX via the Svelte test files, but if I import both React AND Svelte configurations I can still see the React components behaving properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this discussion on github : https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3889

It's not possible now and it's planned for the v7.0
The official position now is to create two sets of configuration (preview and manager), instanciate two separates storybook, and then use composition to assemble the two storybook into one.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make this the "correct" answer for now.